# How to reference variable ids in Rails seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I am manually seeding a databse in the `seeds.rb` file.  I have somthing like the following:

```
# Users
puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT USER LOGIN'.colorize( :color => :light_blue, :background => :green )
  chris = User.create(:email => "asdf@asdf.com", :password => "asdfasdf", :password_confirmation => "asdfasdf").save!
  teacher1 = User.create(:email => "t1@asdf.com", :password => "asdfasdf", :password_confirmation => "asdfasdf").save!
  student1 = User.create(:email => "s1@asdf.com", :password => "asdfasdf", :password_confirmation => "asdfasdf").save!
```

Later, I create some songs, and want to assign them to a user:

```
# Songs
puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT SONGS'.colorize( :color => :white, :background => :black )
  songs1 = Song.create( title: 't1', content: 'c1', :user_id => chris.index ).save!
  songs2 = Song.create( title: 't2', content: 'c2', user_id: chris.index ).save!
  songs3 = Song.create( title: 't3', content: 'c3', user_id: chris:index ).save!
  songs4 = Song.create( title: 't4', content: 'c4', :user_id => chris.id ).save!
```

You will notice that the column `user_id` has three different attempts, all which fail.
How do I insert the unique index of the users i created earlier using the variable I assigned them [ `chris`, `t1`, and `s1`]?

The [API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) only hase how to do it manually, or using a loop.

Comment: what does `p chris.index` return if you put it before `#songs`?

Comment: Don't you want to insert user's `id` instead of `index` in the songs?

Comment: Extending San's comment: Try using `user_id: chris.id` to insert the unique ID of the user record you created earlier.

Comment: @San Yes, I am trying to use the `id`

Comment: @dax `p chris.id` => `NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for true:TrueClass`   `p chris.id` => `NoMethodError: undefined method 'index' for true:TrueClass`

Comment: @San @MrYoshiji that doesn't work  Error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for true:TrueClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `.save!` method. It returns boolean, thats why `chris`, `teacher1` and `student1` are booleans, not the `objects`. You don't need `save!` because `create` saves the record in the database too, and it returns the object.

Remove `.save!` from each line and use `.id` and you will be good.